# Method that returns new object of anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Let say that I have interface I1 like this:

```
interface I1 {
   public void setNumber(int num);
}
```

I want to create let say public class named *MyClass* that will include method *getI1* that will return new object of anonymous class that implements interface I1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little supplement to Japu_D_Cret's answer: for JDK 8, it could be as short as:

```
public I1 getI1() {
    return num -> {
        // your implementation goes here
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this?

```
public I1 getI1() {
  return new I1() {
    public void setNumber(int num) {
      //do something
    }
  };
}
```

alternativaly you could use instead of `new I1()` any class which implements I1

here's an example which uses the interface Runnable and the class Thread, which implements Runnable

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("main > start");

  System.out.println("main > r = getRunnable()");
  Runnable r = getRunnable();

  System.out.println("main > r.run()");
  r.run();
  System.out.println("main > Stop");
}

public static Runnable getRunnable() {
  return new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      System.out.println("run > Start");
      //do something
      System.out.println("run > Stop");
    }
  };
}
```

output is

```
main > start
main > r = getRunnable()
main > r.run()
run > Start
run > Stop
main > Stop
```